# Best practices python classes

Tags: python, class, oop

I have some code that looks roughly like

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=None):
        self.bar = a
        if c:
            self.data = self.calc(b, c)
    def calc(self, bat, baz):
        """calculates some stuff that feels like should belong with the instance of `Foo`"""
```

1. Is it bad to have code within my `__init__`?
2. If I have a method that generates some data relating to the class instance, is it better practice to leave the user to call that method and store the data, or have one of the instance variables store it upon instantiation?

The reason for 2 is because I have this class where everything can be generated from some `json` file, so should the class just have one instance variable and a bunch of methods? Should this not even be a class? I always thought that classes with one instance variable were bad practice, but on the other hand, I have a group of functions that all operate on the same `json` file so they feel like they should belong in some conglomerate structure.

**EDIT:** As a third question, relating to 2, what if some of the methods require data that depends on the initialized data, *and* calculated data. So in the example above, suppose I (the user) calculate `d=2*a+b` because it is of interest to me. Then I want to do another computation that in theory would be sped up if I gave it `d`. So a method that looked like `new_calc(self, d)`. Should I store `d` in the class when I calculate it initially, then not ask the user for it, or should I make them more responsible?

Comment: Just one point: you should set `self.data` to a sensible default value if `c` is None. Also note that `bool(c)` might eval to `False` for (at least) empty lists, empty tuples, empty sets, empty dicts, empty strings and numeric zeros (ints, floats or Decimal).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers right of course. i may have made a MWE that isn't very good practice... oops

Comment: Also if you're using Python 2.x, you want to inherit from `object` to get a "new-style" class that will properly support computed attributes and `super()` calls.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that good OO design aims to minimize the need for method sequencing/dependency by outside code - i.e. *remember to call f() before you call g()*. Depending on compute cost and likelyhood **d** will end up being needed, sure why not @ init.  On the other hand, a *property* w cache might work too.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it bad to have code within my **init**?

No. But if it does anything complicated, factor out the code into a function/method, just like you did with calc. Only I'd suggest that you use `_calc` instead of `calc` if the only caller of that method is the constructor. That way, you signal to users of the class that they're not meant to call `_calc` themselves.

A nitpick:

```
if c:
   self.data = self.calc(b, c)
```

I'd be wary of this code, because if c is None (or 0, or False), 
`self.data` remains unset. So all the rest of your methods have to 
check whether the `data` attribute exists. It might be better to write

```
self.data = self.calc(b, c) if c is None else None
```

Or you could just move the check for None into `calc` method and have the line in the constructor say

```
self.data = self.calc(b, c)
```

> is it better practice to leave the user to call that method

I'd think that depended on the exact use case. If each instance represented a specific data set, and there was no need to swap out one set of data for another one, I'd say it makes more sense for the constructor to do it. This way, the data is nicely encapsulated by the instance, and the user can't make a stupid mistake by changing the data when it isn't supposed to change.

Comment: right, make `calc` private, and yes as @brunodesthuilliers pointed out `self.dat` should be set to something regardless. thanks for your answer!